# Django microservices within Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, microservices

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.4
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  cache:
    image: redis:4.0.10
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  web:
    build: .
    image: dockerdjangoexample
    command: bash -c "gunicorn demosite.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  redis_data:
```

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.6.5

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --skip-lock --dev
```

The `Nginx` config file is:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
  location / {
         proxy_pass http://web/;
  }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}
```

This all works perfectly. What im trying to figure out now is how I can add a second `Django` app into the mix so I can create a microservice environment.

For example, the existing web app from above would be an API that handles user registration / sign in etc. I would like to add another `Django` API into the mix that would do something else and would also use its own database.

If this were to theoretically ever be put into a production environment, then the first API would be used through urls starting with `www.demosite.com/api/users` and the second API could be used through urls starting with `www.demosite.com/api/widgets`.

Im not sure how to accomplish this from a `Docker` and `Nginx` perspective.

Also, if im doing anything completely wrong so far, please correct me as I am new to this.

Comment: Did you end up creating a separate SSO Django application to handle authentication or did you use services like AWS Cognito? Also, if you have used a separate django project for handling authentication could you please tell me about the details as to what authentication backend settings that go in settings.py of both the projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep doing exactly what you're doing now.  Add the second back-end container to the `docker-compose.yml` file, and add another `location` block to the nginx configuration that routes to the specified service.  For the layout you describe, it might look like

```
location /api/users {
  proxy_pass http://web/;
}
location /api/widgets {
  proxy_pass http://widgets/;
}
```

When you start uttering the phrase "production" you typically wouldn't distribute your code separately from the Docker image.  I would try to remove the `volumes:` directive that copies your local working tree over what's installed in the image, and move the `command:` into a `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  Conversely, you might want to pass in the locations of the PostgreSQL and Redis databases as environment variables, even if they're "normally" in the same Docker Compose setup, in case you want to run them somewhere else (run your database on a dedicated or hosted service that gets regularly backed up, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to learn how to do this in the "correct" way. So I will investigate your suggestions further. There are lots of basics tutorials but not much that shows a complete "production ready" example in a tutorial format.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'd go with Kubernetes instead Docker-Compose.

1. Try adding to compose:

`webAuth:
    build: DockerfileAuth
    image: dockerdjangoexample
    command: bash -c "gunicorn demosite.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
   webAnotherService:
    build: DockerfileAnotherService
    image: dockerdjangoexample
    command: bash -c "gunicorn demosite.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8010"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache`

2. Rename your Dockerfile accordingly.
3. Add your WSGI AnotherService to Nginx.

Another Note: Take a look at Nginx Unit, which is design for (Micro-)Service Architecture - [Nginx Unit](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-unit/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look into this famous nginx proxy docker image "https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy".

You can deploy multiple containers & `docker-gen` will dynamically put entries into your nginx configs by listening to docker sock file.

By default it works on domain basis, start any containers you want proxied with an env var `VIRTUAL_HOST=subdomain.youdomain.com`

If that doesn't solve the purpose, you can try creating your own `docker gen` templates for nginx configs in Golang using this image itself.
Another great feature is you can easily scale up/down your app containers too.

Good luck!